# syncdb fails with django-compositekey

Tags: python, django-models

I'm planning to use django-compositekey to connect to a legacy db that makes use of compound keys. Just to see that everything is working, I created a new Django project with a simple model like this.

```
from django.db import models
from compositekey import db

class Book(models.Model):
id = db.MultiFieldPK("author", "name")
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

if I use django_manage.py sql Books everything seems to be fine, I receive

```
 BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "Books_book" (
"name" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
"author" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE ("author", "name"),
PRIMARY KEY ("author", "name")
)
; 

COMMIT;
```

However, when I try to use syncdb I receive the following error

```
Creating tables ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/islas/pycharm-3.4.1/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py", line 23, in <module>
run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 176, in run_module
fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 82, in _run_module_code
mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader, pkg_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "/home/islas/PycharmProjects/BooksDemo/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line           399, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line   392, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415,  in handle
return self.handle_noargs(**options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 112, in handle_noargs
emit_post_sync_signal(created_models, verbosity, interactive, db)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 216, in emit_post_sync_signal
interactive=interactive, db=db)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 185, in send
response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-   packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 93, in create_permissions
"content_type", "codename"
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 538, in values_list
_fields=fields)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 852, in _clone
c._setup_query()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 995, in _setup_query
self.query.add_fields(self.field_names, True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compositekey/db/models/sql/query.py", line 24, in add_fields
True)
ValueError: need more than 5 values to unpack

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Does anybody have an idea of what might be wrong? I'm new to Django, but as far as I read working with compound primary keys is now possible using django-compositekey.

Thanks in advance,

Alejandro

Comment: You need to use django 1.4 for compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of `Django` you are using...? I got the same problem because i was using `Djnago 1.5.8` and the `compositekey` package does not support Djnago 1.5.8

For composite primary keys, you can use [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) instead of native Django ORM. It can coexist with Django ORM seamlessly.

Comment: I using Django 1.6.5,which I think is the latest official version, any other idea of what else might be the problem?  Thanks!!!

Comment: No, the only issue here is version compatibility. Anyways if you want to use composite primary keys, you can use [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) instead of Django native ORM. SQLAlchemy can coexist with Django ORM.